# Blender doesn't render materials properly on first

Tags: rendering

[image]
[image]
[image]

Why blender doesn't render materials on first 16 pictures and after does everything correctly. Pre-render shows everything right. It only starts rendering properly from 16th frame

Comment: Hello, hard to tell, maybe show a screenshot?

Comment: Hi! I've added two first - these are the weird ones. The last  one- thats how it should look like

Comment: A screenshot of the material node setup and/or the timeline of the object would help to understand what is possibly going wrong.